# EKS ingress-nginx contoller attaching sg to public nlb

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-security-group, ingress-controller, aws-nlb

I've got EKS cluster with managed node group. I'm deploying ingress controller using helm chart `ingress-nginx` version `4.7.1` from repository `https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx`. It creates public nlb. Trying to secure it I came across this info as of 10.08.2023 nlb supports [security groups](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/08/network-load-balancer-supports-security-groups/). Digging more I found some information with possible solutions and annotations to use in this [github topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4018#issuecomment-639971875). So deployed config as per `values.yaml` file:

```
controller:
  ingressClassByName: true
  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx-public
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "k8s.io/ingress-nginx-public"
  ingressClass: nginx-public
  service:
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups: aws_security_group.public_alb.id
      #service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: aws_security_group.public_alb.id
    external:
      enabled: true
```

I've tried both options security-group and extra-security-group. Non worked for me. Everything looks fine, helm chart deployed. I can see above annotations added to created service. However when checking LB in aws console. No SG attached. Tested access via lb url... Wide open (sg created with access rule only for specific IP). Does anyone actually made it work? Any ideas what I could miss?

I prefer to use security groups rather than  `loadBalancerSourceRanges` as it gives more control over who can access and what.

Comment: were you able to make it work? also did loadBalancerSourceRanges work with nlb?

Comment: I was not able to attach sg to nlb. After days of digging found some comments on github saying it's not directly supported.
loadBalancerSourceRanges annotation on the other hand works fine with nlb.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest  to install the AWS Load Balancer Controller to Reference AWS Security Groups to NLB, see [instructions here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/deploy/installation/)

then use the annotations from the [AWS controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6/deploy/security_groups/)

or in the [AWS CNI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html)